# Loading a File into the Eclipse Testing Console (VM)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and have been trying to load a CSV file such that Eclipse's virtual machine can find and recognize it when given the appropriate input in my program. I have already tried the following:

1. Copying it to the SRC folder. This however did not help. I have not tried copying it to the bin folder or any folder such as /src/test.
2. I have also read the [appropriate guide](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help%2Fhtml%2Fmanual%2Fnode125.html) in the official docs. However, I am unable to find the Central Test Editor [as described](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help%2Fhtml%2Fmanual%2Fnode136.html).

How may I load test files, most notably a CSV file, into the virtual console such that it is recognized when the program is being run? I have searched through several other answers as well but cannot grasp this concept.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting it in the root of your project.  When accessing files via code, files are sought in the directory specified in the Java system variable `user.dir` which most often is the root directory of your project.

I'm assuming your attempting to load the file as follows:

```
File file = new File("myCsv.csv");
```

In this scenario the following applies:

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative
>   pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named
>   by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in
>   which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

Comment: Thank you, please allow me to go test this.

Comment: mCode if you still have problems post the code your using to access the file.